# Render to Excel incorrectly

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I've got a table, with a number of groups, and each group is hidden on startup. Each group is expandable/collapsible by the clicking the group above it.

```
+Group1
    +Group2
         +Group3
              Detail
```

On the detail line, it's a sub report, which renders a graph

The report works fine until its exported to Excel. When I expand each group in Excel (+), not all the data is shown for the next group.

However, when I click on the numbers for the group I'm wanting to get, then all the data is shown for that group or detail.

i.e.

```
Excel
[1][2][3][4]
+Group
+Group
+Group
+Group
```

For example, if i click on 1 or 2, not all the data for the groups below, but if I expand by 3 or 4, then all the data for all the groups are there

Has anyone come across this issue? This seems to only when if I have a subreport , otherwise the report works fine in Excel

Comment: How are you expanding the groups? If you're using the visible property, it would be an issue on export to Excel. If you're using the collapsed property, it would not.

Comment: Can you post a reproducible example of the report?

Comment: I'm using the group visibility property, set to false initially and then an expression to toggle visibility on/off. This works fine until I add a reference to a subreport in the detail row. Without it, the expanding/collapsing has all the data in the spreadsheet when exported.